# Вывод выбранных данных из select посредством ajax

Tags: javascript, html, select

Есть два объекта на странице. слева select, справа поле в котором я бы хотел видеть вывод выбранных option.

Вся сложность в том чтобы форма справа заполнялась без перезагрузки. Т.е. пользователь сидит щелкает option и справа в форме эти option сразу отображаются.

это форма

```
    <form action="admissionUser" method="POST" class="form1">
        <select multiple="multiple" id="admissionUser"
                        name="admission[]" id="select1" class="select">
                            <option disabled>Выберите</option>
                            <option value="Показатель 1">1</option>
                            <option value="Показатель 2">2</option>
                            <option value="Показатель 3">3</option>
                            <option value="Показатель 4">4</option>
                    </select>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так. Предотвращает перезагрузку страницы `e.preventDefault()`. Ну суть думаю ясна.

```js
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
  $('#form select option').each(function() {
    formData.append("admission", $(this).val());
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
      //с сервера приходят данные в result и ты их отображаешь на экран
      // к примеру создаёшь рядом <div id ='result'></div>
      $("#result").html("<p>" + result + "</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `id` тега в который нужно выводить результат - `'output'`, то

```
document.getElementById('admissionUser').addEventListener('change', e => 
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = e.target.value;
)
```